# How can a tunnel diode be used as a memory element?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, analog, pn-junction

I read in applications of tunnel diodes that it can be used as a memory element. I am not able to justify or verify this statement. It would be very helpful if a circuit showing logic storage using a tunnel diode is included in the answer.

Comment: Can you link to the article and statement that you read? Have you looked at the VI characteristic of a tunnel diode? Do you know that it has a section in the curve that has negative dynamic resistance (clue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By providing a resistive load line for a tunnel diode, the memory effect can be exploited.

As a kid, buying a tunnel diode from Lafayette Electronics, I found 100 ohm series resistors provided a STEEP enough load line that I could map out the entire I_V curve
(this from memory, of decades_ago tinkering).

However, high_resistance load lines would have the SNAP between states; a coupling capacitor would inject the charge transient needed to flip between states.

I did not evaluate the state_store behavior.

I did use the Tunnel Diode as an oscillator.

=======================================

Andy: from what I recall of the I_V curve(s) for a tunnel/Esaki diode

- a HIGH VOLTAGE and a HIGH RESISTANCE provide the snap_memory

I'd draw an I_V curve, but stackX no longer allows my browser that ability.

Comment: The series resistance has to be low enough to cause a current significantly more than the valley current (in other words) or it won't (appear to) work.

Comment: Back in 1969, I bought some RCA tunnel diodes along with this: RCA Tunnel Diodes for Switching and Microwave Applications, Technical Manual TD-30, ©1963. I still have all this. Pages 52-54 show how tunnel diodes can be used as computer memories. Indeed, the section starts out by stating "Because of its voltage-controlled negative-resistance characteristic, the tunnel diode is an ideal element for computer memories." Frankly, it makes no sense to me now, and didn't back then either, but I can scan the pages and post a link to the scan, if desired.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I agree that "a HIGH VOLTAGE and a HIGH RESISTANCE provide the snap_memory". But why?

Comment: @Ed V, You took me back to the distant 70s, when I, as a student at the same university where I have been teaching until now, first encountered this strange semiconductor device and circuit  phenomenon. Then I did not understand it but I was deeply impressed. I managed to explain it much later, in the middle 10s, when, in a fierce "fight" with orthodox Wikipedians, I tried to explain it to Wikipedia readers. I have told it in [my WP user page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Circuit_dreamer#Wikipedia_contributions) (Negative resistance section). Thanks for your story; it touched me deeply.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Thanks for your comment: it means a lot to me! I bought those first RCA tunnel diodes near the end of freshman year at RPI. I loved the idea that they worked by the quantum mechanical concept of tunneling and I wanted to make an oscillator, which I did. But I had no oscilloscope or power supplies other than batteries and my breadboard was a perf board with spring clips (from Radio Shack). Really crude, but electronics is fantastic for providing opportunities for creativity! Electronics is a wonderful mix of deep, practical, fun and challenging.

Answer (score 3):

This is just to supplement the accepted answer by @analogsystemsrf. Since the OP specifically expressed an interest in seeing a tunnel diode circuit where the tunnel diode was the logic storage element, the next two figures are scans from my hardcopy of the **RCA Tunnel Diodes for Switching and Microwave Applications, Technical Manual TD-30, ©1963 by RCA**.

[image: RCA Manual p. 42]

Credit: My scan of page 42 of the reference above.

[image: RCA Manual p. 43]

Credit: My scan of page 43 of the reference above.

There is **lots more** in this old $1.50 technical manual!

Comment: Ed V, Great thoughts! I remember these boards with spring clips. I have also been thinking a lot about how to make the perfect solderless board. I guess you will be interested to see how I realize my youthful circuit dreams in the [lab of Semiconductor Devices and Basic Circuitry with my students](https://photos.app.goo.gl/6AoUi4VjDrEtszbd6)... and especially the [investigation of the tunnel diode IV curve with a "jump"](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oMDzxehAKUuYgPEJA).

Comment: Thanks for the links: great to see all that! The tunnel diode characteristic curve is magnificent! I used to teach an electronics course for undergrad and beginning chemistry grad students (I am a retired chemistry professor) and especially loved the teaching lab! [Here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/79678) is a temporary link (I will delete in 3 days) to a couple of my photos of my electronics, etc. The quest for the ideal solderless breadboard is something I have been on for many years, as the photos will show. It would be terrific to have that quest be successful!

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Please see my comment directly above! In the excitement of the moment, I forgot to direct it to you!

Comment: Ed V, Interesting devices that remind me of military equipment... Resistors sealed in glass ampoules? In the 80's I had to make a charge amplifier for a vibrometer and I remember that I put such a 1 Gohm "glass" resistor in the DC feedback. Floating battery power supplies and battery input voltage sources? I have always preferred them in laboratory experiments. Another example is a (rechargeable) [battery put into the negative feedback](loop.https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_66a) to see how the op-amp will react to such a disturbance...

Comment: ... Almost a whole computer on prototyping boards? Very flexible and suitable for experiments... I cut multimeter's probes and replace them by needles (a piece of stiff wire) [to easily stick them into the holes of prototyping boards](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Yc1qkbUChSKVuhr86). Similarly, I replace the scope probes by [stiff conductors](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Yg8TqDTE8Tuswj4r6) (blue, red and black in the picture) to stick them directly into the board holes. Of course, this works well for relatively high voltages.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist The thing in the briefcase is my KIM-1 microcomputer, purchased April, 1976. Still works fine (at 1 MHz) in assembly language. For breadboard wire, I use Belden 22 gauge silver plated copper wire, white Teflon insulated: I got 3000 feet surplus, for $3! For inserting wires into the breadboard, I cut the bare wire ends diagonally, so they go right in, and for probes, I bought a set of sewing pins, with colored glass ends. The resistors are 1% glass encapsulated resistors: I bought them surplus by *weight*! I use 9 V batteries for my preamps and such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119040/discussion-between-circuit-fantasist-and-ed-v).